# text disappears when I use inputMask in primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

There is a problem with p:inputMask that I could not understand. I gave nine required area to p:inputMask by putting mask="aaaaaaaaa" . It works fine the problem happens when I write only three letters (below nine letters) and click other fields at screen , the text that I wrote at p:inputMask disappears :( . It works fine when I write nine letters (required letters) at p:inputMask and click other field of the screen, text does not disappear at p:inputMask.

It took a lot time of mine. It should have a simple solution that I could not fine. I would be glad if you can help me.

Here is the Sample Code :

```
 <p:inputMask mask="999" style="width: 25px;text-align: left" readonly="true" value="#  {gercekKrediBasvuruDetayGirisKefilView.evTel1Ilk}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<p:inputMask mask="?999" style="width: 25px;text-align: left" readonly="true" value="#  {gercekKrediBasvuruDetayGirisKefilView.evTel1Ilk}" />
```

---

`mask="999"` requires exactly 3 digits input.

`mask="?999"` requires 3 digits at most.